# Entity Framework initial migration failed with SqlException

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I want to create SQL Server DB/tables using EF Model's code first approach.
Here is my simple model class

```
public class MyApplication
{
    [Key]
    public string AppID { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}
```

and my DBContext class is shown here

```
public class PolicyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public PolicyDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder OptionaBuilder)
    {
        if (OptionaBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            OptionaBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder => builder.EnableRetryOnFailure());
        }
    }
    DbSet<MyApplication> AppRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my config code in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<PolicyDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer("Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB;user id=testuid;Password=testpwd;");
}
```

Then I was able to run the "add-migration initialmigration" command successfully

[image]

but when I run the "update-database" command, it always fail with the following error

```
Error Number:64,State:0,Class:20
A transient exception occurred during execution. The operation will be retried after 15024ms.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)
```

After executing "update-database" however, I notice that the new database always get created on my SQL Server, but with no tables in it. I think that indicates that at least my connection string is good.

As you can see from code above, I did EnableRetryOnFailure, as suggested by people in responding to issues similar to mine. But it doesn't solve my problem except that it will retry a few times (6) before finally gives up.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it works this way but I now know how to fix it. It appears that I need to run update-database command twice. The first time will fail but, as I mentioned in my post, the new empty DB will be created. Now, leave the empty DB there - DO NOT DELETE IT! - and run the update-database command again. This time it will succeed and the tables will be created.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approach in the code first option. You should use protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ }
You should define configuration in this method.

For more details, visit this [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx).